# Find the shortest path from bottom left to top right in a maze using dfs and bfs algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

The following code is applying the depth-first search and breadth-first search algorithm to find the shortest path from bottom left to top right in a `10 x 10` grid. I need reviews to improve my implementation and code quality.

Graph.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma once
using namespace std;
struct point{
    int x, y;
    bool operator>(point pnt){
        return (this->x > pnt.x) && (this->y > pnt.y);
    }
};
struct node{
    char val; 
    bool visited; 
    point prev;
    node(char v = 0){
        val = v;
        visited = false;
        prev = {-1, -1};
    }
};
class GRAPH{
    size_t rows, cols;
    char route;
    node** nodes = nullptr;
public:
    GRAPH(size_t n, size_t m, char **vals = nullptr, char rout = '*'){
        rows = n;
        cols = m;
        route = rout;
        if(vals){
            nodes = new node*[rows];
            for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                nodes[i] = new node[cols];
                for(size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                    nodes[i][j] = (vals[i][j]);
                }
            }
            for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                delete vals[i];
            delete[]vals;
        }
    }
    void display(){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                cout << nodes[i][j].val << ' ';
            cout << '\n';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    bool inside_graph(point pnt){
        return pnt.x < rows && pnt.y < cols; 
    }
    bool is_on_route(point pnt){
        return this->inside_graph(pnt) && this->at(pnt).val == route;
    }
    node& at(point pnt){
        return nodes[pnt.x][pnt.y];
    }
    point size(){
        return {rows, cols};
    }
    ~GRAPH(){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            delete nodes[i];
        delete[]nodes;
    }
};
```

Solve.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
#include "graph.h"
using namespace std;
int dfs_cnt = 0, bfs_cnt = 0;
GRAPH init_graph();
void DFS(GRAPH&, point, point);
void BFS(GRAPH&, point, point);
void solve(GRAPH&, bool);
void mark(GRAPH&, char);
int main()
{
    GRAPH graph_for_DFS = init_graph();
    DFS(graph_for_DFS, {graph_for_DFS.size().x - 1, 0}, {0, graph_for_DFS.size().y - 1});
    mark(graph_for_DFS, '+');
    graph_for_DFS.display();
    solve(graph_for_DFS, 0);

    GRAPH graph_for_BFS = init_graph();
    BFS(graph_for_BFS, {graph_for_BFS.size().x - 1, 0}, {0, graph_for_BFS.size().y - 1});
    mark(graph_for_BFS, '+');
    graph_for_BFS.display();
    solve(graph_for_BFS, 1);
    return 0;
}
GRAPH init_graph(){
    dfs_cnt = bfs_cnt = 0;
    ifstream maze("Maze.txt");
    size_t n, m;
    maze >> n >> m;
    char **grid = new char* [n];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++){
        grid[i] = new char[m];
        maze >> grid[i];
    }
    maze.close();
    return GRAPH(n, m, grid);
}
void DFS(GRAPH& graph, point src, point dest){
    dfs_cnt++;
    if(src > dest)
        return;
    point tmp = {src.x - 1, src.y};
    if(graph.is_on_route(tmp) && !graph.at(tmp).visited){
        graph.at(tmp).visited = true;
        graph.at(tmp).prev = src;
        DFS(graph, tmp, dest);
    }
    tmp = {src.x, src.y + 1};
    if(graph.is_on_route(tmp) && !graph.at(tmp).visited){
        graph.at(tmp).visited = true;
        graph.at(tmp).prev = src;
        DFS(graph, tmp, dest);
    }
}
void BFS(GRAPH& graph, point src, point dest){
    queue<point> q;
    q.push(src);
    point curr = src;
    while(!q.empty() && !(curr > dest)){
        curr = q.front();
        graph.at(curr).visited = true;
        q.pop();
        point tmp = {curr.x - 1, curr.y};
        bfs_cnt++;
        if(graph.is_on_route(tmp) && !graph.at(tmp).visited){
            q.push(tmp);
            graph.at(tmp).visited = true;
            graph.at(tmp).prev = curr;
            bfs_cnt++; 
        }
        tmp = {curr.x, curr.y + 1};
        if(graph.is_on_route(tmp) && !graph.at(tmp).visited){
            q.push(tmp);
            graph.at(tmp).visited = true;
            graph.at(tmp).prev = curr;
            bfs_cnt++;
        }
    }
}
void mark(GRAPH& graph, char mrk){
    for(node *tmp = &graph.at({0, graph.size().y - 1}); tmp != &graph.at({graph.size().x - 1, 0}); tmp = &graph.at(tmp->prev))
        tmp->val = mrk;
    graph.at({graph.size().x - 1, 0}) = mrk;
}
void solve(GRAPH& graph, bool is_BFS){
    ofstream sol(is_BFS ? "BFS_Solved_Maze.txt" : "DFS_Solved_Maze.txt");
    size_t n = graph.size().x, m = graph.size().y;
    sol << (is_BFS? bfs_cnt : dfs_cnt) << '\n';
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            sol << graph.at({i, j}).val << ' ';
        sol <<'\n';
    }
}
```

Maze.txt

```
10 10
########**
########**
#######**#
##******##
##*****###
##*****###
#***######
#*########
**########
**########
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison operator in `point` is broken, as you have many points that are not equal (equivalent) but neither is greater that the other. The usual way for comparing two values in a struct like this is to only look at the second element if the first values are equal. You could make a [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) from the two points and compare those. Using [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) is an easy way to do this. The member function should be `const`, and the parameter should be passed by a const reference (although some would disagree when passing a small struct such as `point`).

```
bool operator>(const point &pnt) const {
    return std::tie(x, pnt.x) > std::tie(y, pnt.y);
}
```

You use a lot of manual memory management in `GRAPH`. You're missing copy and move constructors and assignment operators, which will lead to memory problems. This violates the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) (or [five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)). Replace it all with `std::vector`, and the memory management will all be taken care of for you (also, the destructor could then be omitted or defaulted).

The constructor for `GRAPH` assumes that the values have been allocated. As it does not own the memory passed in by `vals`, it should not attempt to free it. It might also be helpful (for the longer term use of the class) to have a default constructor and a way to resize an existing GRAPH object.

`display`, `inside_graph`, and `is_on_route` should also be const member functions. Consider adding in an overload of `at` that is a const member function that returns by value (or const reference). In the standard library, member functions named `at` will perform bounds checking, and throw an exception if a subscript is out of bounds. You could add that to `at`, and add two overloads for `operator[]` that would not perform the bounds checking.